# Can't map caps lock to ctrl after installed fcitx

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, fcitx

My system is 14.04 ubuntu LTS.

I was using `IBus` as my input method and mapped caps lock to ctrl by adding `XKBOPTIONS=“ctrl:nocaps` to my `/etc/default/keyboard`. But lately I changed to `fcitx` and I can't map my caps lock to ctrl anymore.

I've tried `Tweak Tool`. But neither it worked.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [Issue](https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx/issues/148)

I found this command works pretty well `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`.